# How do I use RxJS & Observables to do an http request only after multiple other events have fired?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, twitch, rxjs-observables

I am having trouble combining the emitted values of two different `Observable`s for use in an http request, and then returning the request's `Observable` for use by clients.

Some background: I am working on a Twitch extension. Part of their ecosystem is that extensions receive environment information through event callbacks. The ones I am interested in are located at `window.Twitch.ext.onAuthorized()` and `window.Twitch.ext.configuration.onChanged()` (if interested, see here for more details: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/extensions/reference#helper-extensions).

When making calls to my backend, I need information from both of the above events. These will not change often (if ever), but I can't make calls until they are both available, and I want to get the most recently provided value when making calls. It looks like `BehaviorSubject`s would be ideal for this:

```
export class TwitchService {
  private authSubject: BehaviorSubject<TwitchAuth> = new BehaviorSubject<TwitchAuth>(null);
  private configSubject: BehaviorSubject<TwitchConfig> = new BehaviorSubject<TwitchConfig>(null);
  private helper: any;

  constructor(private window: Window) {
    this.helper = this.window['Twitch'].ext;
    this.helper.onAuthorized((auth: TwitchAuth) => {
      this.authSubject.next(auth);
    });
    this.helper.configuration.onChanged(() => {
      this.configSubject.next(JSON.parse(this.helper.configuration.global.content));
    });
  }

  onAuthorized(): Observable<TwitchAuth> {
    return this.authSubject.asObservable().pipe(filter((auth) => !!auth));
  }

  onConfig(): Observable<TwitchConfig> {
    return this.configSubject.asObservable().pipe(filter((config) => !!config));
  }
}
```

This model works well for parts of the app that subscribe to one of those two `Observable`s. My problem is I cannot find a working way to combine them and use the latest emitted values from both to create a single-use `Observable` for http requests.

Here's what I have so far:

```
type twitchStateToObservable<T> = (auth: TwitchAuth, config: TwitchConfig) => Observable<T>;

export class BackendService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private twitch: TwitchService) {}

  private httpWithTwitchState<T>(f: twitchStateToObservable<T>): Observable<T> {
    let subject = new Subject<T>();
    combineLatest(this.twitch.onAuthorized(), this.twitch.onConfig()).pipe(
      first(), // because we only want to make the http request one time
      map(([auth, config]) => f(auth, config).subscribe((resp) => subject.next(resp)))
    );
    return subject.asObservable();
  }

  exampleHttpRequest(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpWithTwitchState((auth, config) =>
      // this.url() and this.headers() are private functions of this service
      this.http.get<Response>(this.url(config) + 'exampleHttpRequest', { headers: this.headers(auth, config)})
    );
  }
}
```

And then, a client of this service should be able to make http requests with this simple call, without needing to know anything about the events or care when they fire:

```
this.backend.exampleHttpRequest().subscribe((resp) => {
  // do stuff with resp here...but this is never hit
}
```

Based on my understanding, `combineLatest()` should emit new values whenever either of the input `Observable`s emits a new value. However, the call `f(auth, config)` inside of `map()` is never triggered in my application. I've tested it with breakpoints, with `console.log`s, and by keeping an eye on the Network tab in the browser debugger tools. It's possible the call to `first()` is throwing it off, but I don't want to repeat the http request if the events fire again, for obvious reasons.

Thanks in advance for any advice or pointers!

Comment: Despite some non-idiomatic usage of RxJS, it looks like it should work. Are you sure that `helper.onAuthorized` and `helper.configuration.onChanged` callbacks are actually triggered in `TwitchService`. I can imagine a case where helper has emitted its events before TwitchService has been instantiated.

Comment: @amakhrov good idea - I tested it out with some breakpoints. `TwitchService` constructor is hit first, then `httpWithTwitchState()` is hit (because another component is making an http call in its `ngOnInit()`), then both of the events fire in `TwitchService`. That matches up with my expected order of events. Do you have anything I could read about idiomatic usage of RxJS? Maybe if I clean that up the problem will fix itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I was missing something obvious. I was not subscribing to the `combineLatest()` call, so it was never being executed. After adding a `subscribe()` at the end, this worked fine:

```
private httpWithTwitchState<T>(f: twitchStateToObservable<T>): Observable<T> {
  let subject = new Subject<T>();
  combineLatest(this.twitch.onAuthorized(), this.twitch.onConfig()).pipe(
      first(),
      map(([auth, config]) => f(auth, config).subscribe((resp) => subject.next(resp)))
  ).subscribe(); // adding this fixed the problem
  return subject.asObservable();
}
```

After doing that, I did a little more research about how to un-nest subscriptions in cases like this, which led me to the `flatMap()` operator. So now the `httpWithTwitchState()` function looks like this:

```
private httpWithTwitchState<T>(f: twitchStateToObservable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return combineLatest(this.twitch.onAuthorized(), this.twitch.onConfig()).pipe(
    first(),
    map(([auth, config]) => f(auth, config)),
    flatMap((resp) => resp)
  );
}
```

This works as expected now and is cleaner. Thanks to those who took the time to read my question and/or reply.

Comment: Good catch! Btw, That's a part of the "non-idiomatic rxjs code" :). There is no need to create a new subject inside httpWithTwitchState. And furthermore, no need to subscribe inside map() operator (which is actually bad - `map` is designed for data transformation and not for side effects.

Comment: Instead, this method would look like: `return combineLatest([onAuth, onConfig]).pipe(first(), switchMap(([auth, conf]) => f(auth, conf)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can think of concat like a line at a ATM, the next transaction (subscription) cannot start until the previous completes!

Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3qsfgk?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Sample:

```
const mergeValue = concat(authSubject,configSubject) 

mergeValue.subscribe( (x) => {
  // do stuff with resp here
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer - but I don't think `concat` fits my use case here. I'm trying to coordinate the output of two events that I don't have control over when they fire, and do an http call only after they have both fired, using the data from each.